# how to transfer data from documentdb to redshift using AWS glue (ETL jobs)

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I am currently transferring data from Documentdb to s3 but not able to transfer to redshift, maybe I missed something, so can you please specify steps to follow so that I can transfer to redshift.

Comment: Could you add your code and the errors you are facing?

Comment: Are you using Glue to extra data from DocumentDB and load into S3?